# Importing variables from python scripts dynamically

Tags: python, import

How do I include a var from file in a recursive function?

What I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

def parseFile(pathToFile : str):
    print(pathToFile)
    fileVars = __import__(pathToFile, None, None, ['fileList'], 0)        
    for file in fileVars.fileList:
            parseFile(file)

parseFile(sys.argv[1])
```

There are two problems with this code:

- The include statement executes the imported script (I don't want to change the script).
- It doesn't find files in subfolders.

I don't want to parse the file manually and I want to refrain from including extra dependencies if possible.

I know that above is hacky. The question is: (how) can I accomplish what I want with amount of hacking that will be cleaner overall then writing/including (external) parser.

Comment: Care to explain down vote? I did my homework. I can't find any more useful information on the Internet. I'm a beginner in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a help of a friend I got it:

```
import ast

def getVarFromPy(pathToFile: str, varName: str):
    my_ast = ast.parse(open(pathToFile).read()) # fd will be collected by GC sometime in the future
    return next(eval(compile(ast.Expression(obj.value), '<ast>', mode='eval')) for obj in my_ast.body if 
                isinstance(obj, ast.Assign) and obj.targets[0].id == varName)
```

Surprisingly clean.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a file named `__init__.py` in the subfolders. This can be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I want the solution to be contained in the main script. (I wanted to up vote Your comment bur unfortunately I don't have enough rep.)